# PyQt - Set model of a proxymodel in QThread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread

In my project i noticed that the main dialog freezes when it is setting the model of some ProxyModel, so i decided to create a new thread for this task to provide the responsiveness of the window, but right now it keeps popping an error that say:
TypeError: QTableView.setModel(QAbstractItemModel): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'

and i don't know why...
Here's my code:

This is the QThread for updating the proxyModel with the arguments i provide

```
class ThreadedProxyModel(QThread):
    def __init__(self, contacts, contactsProxyModel, groups, groupsProxyModel,
                 chatSession, chatSessionProxyModel, msgs, msgsProxyModel):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.contacts = contacts
        self.contactsProxyModel = contactsProxyModel
        self.groups = groups
        self.groupsProxyModel = groupsProxyModel
        self.chatSession = chatSession
        self.chatSessionProxyModel = chatSessionProxyModel
        self.msgs = msgs
        self.msgsProxyModel = msgsProxyModel

    def run(self):
        self.contactsProxyModel.setSourceModel(recordsTableModel(self.contacts))
        self.contactsProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.contactsProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.groupsProxyModel.setSourceModel(recordsTableModel(self.groups))
        self.groupsProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.groupsProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.chatSessionProxyModel.setSourceModel(recordsTableModel(self.chatSession))
        self.chatSessionProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.chatSessionProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.msgsProxyModel.setSourceModel(recordsTableModel(self.msgs))
        self.msgsProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.msgsProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

    def getContactsProxyModel(self):
        return self.contactsProxyModel,

    def getGroupsProxyModel(self):
        return self.groupsProxyModel

    def getChatSessionProxyModel(self):
        return self.chatSessionProxyModel

    def getMsgsProxyModel(self):
        return self.msgsProxyModel
```

And this is the method calling the setProxyModel thread in the dialog class. Notice that all the data (contacts, groups, chatsession...) is fine:

```
def setProxyModel(self):
    progress = QProgressDialog("Initializing UI ...", "Abort", 0, 0, self)
    progress.setWindowTitle("WhatsApp Browser ...")
    progress.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
    progress.setMinimumDuration(0)
    progress.setCancelButton(None)
    progress.show()

    queryTh = ThreadedProxyModel(self.contacts, self.contactsProxyModel, self.groups, self.groupsProxyModel,
                                 self.chatSession, self.chatSessionProxyModel, self.msgs, self.msgsProxyModel,)
    queryTh.start()
    while queryTh.isRunning():
        QApplication.processEvents()

    self.contactsProxyModel = queryTh.getContactsProxyModel()
    self.groupsProxyModel = queryTh.getGroupsProxyModel()
    self.chatSessionProxyModel = queryTh.getChatSessionProxyModel()
    self.msgsProxyModel = queryTh.getMsgsProxyModel()

    progress.close()
```

And this is in the **init** method in my dialog, i create the proxymodels and call the method for updating them in the Thread and then i set them up in various QTableView:

```
self.contactsProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.groupsProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.groupMembersProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.chatSessionProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.chatMsgsProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.msgsProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)

self.setProxyModel()

self.contactsTableView.setModel(self.contactsProxyModel)
self.contactsTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

self.groupsTableView.setModel(self.groupsProxyModel)
self.groupsTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

self.chatSessionTableView.setModel(self.chatSessionProxyModel)
self.chatSessionTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

self.chatSessionTableView.clicked.connect(self.setChatMsgsProxyModel)
self.chatMsgsTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

self.groupsTableView.clicked.connect(self.setGroupMembersProxyModel)
self.groupMembersTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

self.msgsTableView.setModel(self.msgsProxyModel)
self.msgsTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Thank you for any advice, i'm pretty stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it seems that

```
def getContactsProxyModel(self):
   return self.contactsProxyModel,
```

return a tuple, try to delete the comma

Comment: oh my god... stupid comma... thank you very much!
but the dialog still freezes, any suggestion about that? At this point a think that is setting the model in the QTableViews that freezes it... should i move that too to a QThread?

Comment: Accessing Qt objects from multiple threads is very risky. The QObject class is re-entrant (models subclass QObject rather than QWidget) so in theory I think you could create a model in another thread with no problems, and then move it to the main thread using QObject.moveToThread() before connecting it with a view. However I expect the slow part of your program is the view reading data out of the model, and so that will not help with speed. NOt sure there is anything you can do to be honest. Qt threading guide: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html